# Abrir uma galeria via ID com LightBox

Tags: php, lightbox

Estou com dificuldade em fazer o [LightBox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) abrir uma galeria especifica que carregue as imagens de certo diretório. Neste momento o código abaixo, lista várias miniaturas, que seria os álbuns de imagens. Quando abro uma imagem, ele funciona o recurso, mas lista as miniaturas, e não o que está no diretório daquela `ID`.

Será que isto é possível. As imagens ficam separadas em diretórios diferentes conforme a `ID` da galeria. Está gravado o caminho no banco de dados, e o arquivo em um diretório. Vejam meu código:

**PHP**

```php
foreach($dados_fotos as $gal) {
    $fotos_treinamento .= <<<HTML
        <div class="medium-3 columns end">
            <a rel="lightbox[]" data-group="gallery-{$gal['galeria']}" href="http://sistema/public/uploads/fotos/{$gal['galeria']}/{$gal['foto']}">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-section">
                        <img data-galery="gallery-{$gal['galeria']}" src="http://sistema/public/uploads/fotos/{$gal['galeria']}/{$gal['foto']}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
HTML;
}
```

**EDIT**

Consulta do banco, no banco fica gravado o ID da galeria, o ID da imagem, e o caminho da foto.

O diretório na pasta onde fica os arquivos físicos é o mesmo do ID da galeria. ex: `fotos/ID_GALERIA/arquivo.jpg`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi a tag `javascript` se está a usar `php`...

Comment: Corrigi, obrigado

Comment: qual os dados que `$dados_fotos` recebe, ou mehlor como ele pega esses dados ?

Comment: Se pode colocar isso na pergunta para eu visualizar... Num parece algo muito difícil, mas tô meio devagar para processar hj..hehe Mas põe o código....

Comment: Editei lá amigo

Comment: essa miniatura que se refere, é o arquivo e ele está sendo apresentado como miniatura (devido a interferência do plugin) ou é outro arquivo ?

Comment: É o primeiro arquivo do array

Comment: estou com um pouco de dificuldade de entender..."mas lista as miniaturas, e não o que está no diretório daquela ID" , Tomando por base a tabela que mandou, qual é exatamente o nome do arquivo e o `path` que está sendo retornado ?

Comment: O que quero acredito ser parecido com esse link http://wbruno.com.br/ajax/usando-lightbox-em-pagina-carregada-ajax/ veja se consegue entender melhor

Comment: Desculpe,  o link não está carregando, se puder responder a pergunta anterior...

Comment: Sim as imagens estão no diretório daquela ID e o diretorio equivale a id por exemplo no banco tenho a imagem xxxx.jpg de galeria 5. O diretorio sera uploads/fotos/5/xxxx.jpg